# Why does resolve not function as I expect in angular-strap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I have been attempting to shift from ui-angular to angular-strap.  I first shifted to using bs-tooltip instead of tooltip.  This part is working fine.  Next I attempted to shift my modals and here I am stuck!!! I have been attempting to inject my data into the controller as follows:

```
var myModal = $modal({
templateContent: 'addTask.html',
controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl2',
show: false,
resolve: {
    function () {
      return {
        data: new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          resolve({
            task: newTask,
            getStar: $scope.getStar,
            setPriority: userCondition.setTaskPriority,
            finish: function(arg) {
              console.log(arg);
            }
          }); 
        })
      };
    }
  }
});

myModal.$promise.then(function() {
  myModal.show();
});
```

where my controller `ModalInstanceContrl2` is:

```
angular.module('...')
 .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl2', ['$scope', '$modal', 'data',
    function($scope, $modal, data) {

      console.log(data);

      $scope.ok = function () {
        $modal.close();
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modal.dismiss('cancel');
      };

      $scope.data = data;

   }]);
```

Yet no matter how I seem to manipulate this 'resolve', I always see:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data <- ModalInstanceCtrl2
```

And the only model for this that I understand comes from ui-angular.  So even though angular-strap seems to talk about having checked in code to recognize 'resolve', in doesn't see to be in the current release???

So I am clueless about how to actually inject data into the controller.  Could someone help??? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I sure wish that the docs for angular-strap were better!! -- Yet it doesn't make too much sense to complain, since I am only using this and not a contributor!

For others attempting to get this working. What I did in the end was to debug the angular-strap code and I learned to do:

```
  var myModal = $modal({
    templateUrl: 'addTaskOld.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl2',
    show: false,
    resolve: {
      data: function () {
        return {
          task: newTask,
          getStar: $scope.getStar,
          setPriority: userCondition.setTaskPriority,
          finish: function (arg) {
            console.log(arg);
          }
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

where my templateUrl: is just what was in my earlier content, but with the expected bootstrap fully modal dialog structure.  I did this to gain full control of the template.

I also didn't bother with the Promise injection from above, since I didn't really need it, I only added it since I thought perhaps returning a Promise would help it function.  But it was not needed.

I still have much to learn, but at least now I see what I expect in my modal and I suspect that this will help others beginning to work with angular-strap. I spent a few hours attempting to get this working and it's a bit more difficult coming from ui-angular since the style here is attribute oriented instead of element oriented.

It should be straight forward from here.

Thanks to those who looked at this question!

Note I also needed to change the modalInstanceCtrl2 slightly as I was not calling the correct methods:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl2', ['$scope', '$modal', 'data',
  function($scope, $modal, data) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    data.finish(data);
    $scope.$hide();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.$hide();
  };

  $scope.data = data;

}]);
```